# Do I have to set every properties initial value in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a beginner in react. I have a function that makes a request to an API and return the response as JSON

```
 const [datastate, setData] = useState({});
 const getData = async () => {
     const response = await fetch(`https://MY_API_REQUEST_URL_HERE`);
     const data = await response.json();
     setData(data);
     console.log(data);      // works
     console.log(datastate); // Empty object is returned in console 
 }
```

I want to initialize my **datastate** with the response that is returned from the API, i.e with **data** variable.

But I recently figured out that the reason why it's returning empty object it's because I don't have any properties defined in useState so to be precise I have to do something like this:

```
const [datastate, setData] = useState({
    username: "",
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
});
```

But the problem is the data returned by API is complex, it contains an array of object, an object containing another object containing array. So I was thinking is there a shortcut to do this, that is I don't have to define every property in useState that I want to use.

App.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Data from "./Data";
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [datastate, setData] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [datastate]);  // Added as suggested by William Wang

    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID}&app_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_APP_KEY}&ingr=1%20pie%20pizza`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(datastate);
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form className="search-form">
                <input className="search-bar" type="text" />&nbsp;
                <button className="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <Data data={datastate} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

please note that the JSX inside return is incomplete, please focus on the Data componenet inside return

Data.js

```
import React from "react";

function Data({data}) {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>
                {data.users[0].username}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Data;
```

Also note that the data.users gives error as if no props are passed to the Data component.

Comment: State is updated asynchronously. Even is you provide initial values for the state, logging `datastate` immediately after calling `setData` will give you the previous state, not the new one. If you want to log the updated state value, use `useEffect` hook: `useEffect(() => { console.log(datastate); }, [datastate]);`

Comment: You'd have to set defaults in vue, where setting state works differently (has pros and cons), but i don't think that's necessary in react. What other comments and answers mention applies, but i don't understand, why setting initial properties would cause a behavioral change. You'd still get exactly what you set as the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setData` is the asynchronous method, so you can't get the updated value of `datastate` immediately after `setData()`

```
const getData = async () => {
     const response = await fetch(`https://MY_API_REQUEST_URL_HERE`);
     const data = await response.json();
     setData(data);
     console.log(datastate); // old value of `datastate` will be displayed.
 }
```

You should use `useEffect()` to get the updated value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(datastate);
}, [datastate]);
```

---

**Update**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(datastate);
    }, [datastate]);  // Added as suggested by William Wang

    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID}&app_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_APP_KEY}&ingr=1%20pie%20pizza`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(datastate); // This is wrong way to check the updated datastate value.
    }
```

Comment: I cannot access the data in the component why? In the console the `console.log(datastate)` first prints empty object and then both `console.log(data)` and `console.log(datastate)`prints the object a bunch of times correctly but I cannot access the object in the component as if no data is passed

Comment: you need to call getData() not in the useEffect that has the datastate dependency, but just call it in another useEffect with empty dependency which means componentDidMount. what i meant is you can't console.log() the updated datastate right after setData(), but you just need to check it in the useEffect() with adding a datastate dependency which is always triggered when datastate is updated.

Comment: So I'll have 2 useEffect one with datastate dependency and other with nothing in which I'll have to call getData() so the code would look like this right? `useEffect ( () => {}, [datastate] )` and `useEffect ( () => { getData() } )` the function inside useEffect with datastate dependency has an empty body is that okay?

Comment: you can remove the datastate dependency useEffect after you check datastate is updated properly.